# How to Get Customer data by telephone number in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, customer-address

I have a telephone number which is given in Default address..by using this telephone  number i need to get Customer Full data.Data like customer id, customer full name..etc

Comment: Address Phone number ? or you created new customer attribute ?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Try to explain your issue in details also if you have tried any code put in here. It will be much easy to help you.

Comment: It is default Billing Address -> Phone number.

Comment: Please check the below code and get back with u r feedback thanks

Comment: Please let me know whether it's working or not. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have a **rest** tag , I assume you want to get it via **REST API**.

You can construct a GET request to `<yoursite.com>/rest/<store_code>/V1/customers/search` with the following parameters:

> searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]:
>   addresses[telephone]
>
> searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value] : 123456789
>
> searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]: eq

Of course, you've to add admin token on header or you'll likely to get permission denied error.

[Reference](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/customerCustomerRepositoryV1/customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetListGet)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in test.php and run the same in the root folder.

```
<?php 

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
    include('app/bootstrap.php'); 
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
    // Get Store ID
    $store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
    $customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory'); 
    $customer=$customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    //$customer->loadByEmail('roni_cost@example.com');// load customer by email address
    //echo $customer->getEntityId();
    // $customer->load('1');// load customer by using ID
    //$data= $customer->getData();
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('customer_address_entity');    
    $sql = "SELECT parent_id FROM `customer_address_entity` WHERE `telephone`='987456123' ";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    $myCustomerId='';
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        $myCustomerId = $value['parent_id'];
    }
    $customer->load($myCustomerId);
    echo "<pre>";
    $data= $customer->getData();
    print_r($data);

   echo 'Lastname=='.$data['lastname']."</br>";
   echo 'DOB=='.$data['dob'];
    
    ?>
```

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fss6ql

Answer (score 0):

Let us $telephone_number is value of current customer's telephone number than you can use $customer and get your data like as:-

```
$customer->load($telephone_number,'telephone_number');
$customer->getData();
```